# How can tornado set_status 307

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

I use tornado 4.3 in python 2.7 . I want to redirect one request to another one.For example, when I POST http://127.0.0.1/ , I wanna it posting to https://myip.ipip.net/.This can be done by nginx using conf below

```
return  307  $scheme://myip.ipip.net$request_uri;
```

But now the target URL is not always the same so I cannot hard code in nginx.
As my server is tornado , I should make it work using code.
As we know tornado supports set HTTP code using `self.set_status(HTTP_CODE)`.
But when I set 307 it responses 302 to client.What's wrong ?

Here is my code

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.set_status(307)
        self.redirect("https://myip.ipip.net/") #

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here is my test with curl.Tornado responsed 302 though I set 307.

`curl -LI 127.0.0.1:8888 -XPOST`

Result is below

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 07:31:17 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://myip.ipip.net/
Server: TornadoServer/4.3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: NewDefend
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 07:31:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 69
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache:  from ctl-zj-122-228-198-138
```

Thank you ！

Comment: I found reason in source code... `self.redirect(url,permanent=False, status=None)` ,default status is 302 or 301 ... ,so set status in self.redirect can do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`redirect` takes a `status` parameter](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.redirect):

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.redirect("https://myip.ipip.net/", status=307)
```